# Error running presto query on kinesis

Tags: amazon-kinesis, presto, qubole

I am getting following error while running presto query on kinesis.

> Query 20151031_142753_00003_xxxxx failed: Rate exceeded for stream xxxxx under account xxxxxx. (Service: AmazonKinesis; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ProvisionedThroughputExceededException; Request ID: 94fb720d-7fdb-11e5-994c-83dc0xxxxxx)

I'm using qubole's presto-kinesis connector.

Any Ideas, How to fix

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when client tries to read data at a faster rate than Kinesis shard's limit (2mb/s).
Add a retry logic over the getRecords call to shards.